# Viewpager changes the pictures from page 1 to page 2 , by pressing button, but does not by sliding

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, android-viewpager, adapter

This is the listener i have on my viewPager:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                pageNr.setText("page: " + (viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1) + "/" + viewPager.getChildCount());
                currentSlide = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                page = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                viewPager.setAdapter(new SubcategoriesPagerAdapter(getActivity(), inflater, videos, numberOfPages));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
        });
```

This are my buttons:

```
 nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToNextSlide();
                pageNr.setText("page: " + (viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1) + "/" + viewPager.getChildCount());
                if (categ == 2) {
                    numberOfPages = 2;
                }
                viewPager.setAdapter(new SubcategoriesPagerAdapter(getActivity(), inflater, videos, numberOfPages, categ));
            }
        });
        previousBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToPreviousSlide();
                pageNr.setText("page: " + (viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1) + "/" + viewPager.getChildCount());
                if (categ == 2) {
                    numberOfPages = 2;
                }
                viewPager.setAdapter(new SubcategoriesPagerAdapter(getActivity(), inflater, videos, numberOfPages, categ));
            }
        });
      private void goToNextSlide() {
        currentSlide = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        page = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (currentSlide < viewPager.getChildCount()) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentSlide + 1);
        }
    }

    private void goToPreviousSlide() {
        currentSlide = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        page = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (currentSlide > 0) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentSlide - 1);
        }
    }
```

Now if i press the next or previous button, it changes the pages, and also the pictures from the page (i have 9 pictures, a 3x3 matrix of image views)
When i scroll to the second page, sometimes it changes the pictures, sometimes it doesnt, and also  the viewpager starts to get crazy, sometimes i cannot go back to the first page, from the second, but i can scroll to the right, a unlimited number of times, but everytime it shows the second page. Whan can i do. Or is it possible to make the Viewpage not be scrollable, so i could only change the pages from the buttons?

Comment: You shouldn't set the adapter each time you make a change, either by swipeing or by clicking those buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a Custom ViewPager like this one:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean isPagingEnabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.isPagingEnabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.isPagingEnabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.isPagingEnabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
    this.isPagingEnabled = b;
}
}
```